# Expo Push Notification Topics as Handled by Firebase and AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, expo

Is there a way to send push notification "topics" via Expo Notifications? Also, send push notification to multiple devices at once?

In Firebase or AWS SNS, you can send a push notification to a single device, push notification to multiple devices (Good for a small number of devices), and push notification to devices that are subscribed to a particular topic (Good for a large number of devices).

Or, is there a way to get Expo to work with AWS SNS?